# Why is file upload slower in HTTPS, is Azure throttling me?

Tags: azure, https, glassfish

I have an Azure server "A" with Windows Server 2016. I have an Azure server "B" with Windows Server 2019.

Both are using the same code, same Glassfish Version and configs.

In server "A": -Doesn't matter if i use https or http, speed is 2.3MB/s

In server B -When i send a file over http to a rest service the speed is about 2.3MB/s -when i do this over https ports with security active it goes down to 0.6MB/s

I tried changing various configs in glassfish, tearing down Windows firewall, searched some configs in azure, nothing seems to help server "B" to keep up with the speed.